# Differences between Samadhi and Nirvana

Tags: yoga, meditation, samadhi

I have a few years practising meditation and kriya Yoga but still don't know whats the difference between ***Samadhi and Nirvana***, for me are like the same concept but in different religion.

**¿Is it experienced in different ways?**

I ask for this because on meditation I want to focus on the differents concepts in order to work one or another.

Comment: Nirvana is also term comes in bhairava sadhana. Nirvana means complete emptiness.  Emptiness of manas mind is nirvana. Samadhi is state of oness. One represents seen and other represents seer, the subjective terminology.

Comment: Both are same, just like water's scientific formula is H2O, but water is water, so is Samadhi of Hinduism was logically called as Nirvana by Buddha.

Comment: part of the confusion is different Buddhist schools interpret nirvana differently, and there are different levels of samadhi in Hinduism. Nirvikalpa Samadhi in Hinduism is the same as Buddhist (Mahayana school) Nirvana (emptiness of all things sensual). In Hinayana (Theravedic) Buddhism, Nirvana is a void.